# Why can't I press the Install button when installing applications from unknown sources?

Tags: installation, side-loading, unknown-sources

I'm trying to sideload an application, as seen in the picture below.

[image]

I have allowed the installation of applications from unknown applied actions in settings, but I can't seem to press the install button. The cancel button works correctly and installing applications via `adb install` works correctly. What's the problem?

EDIT: For those who have this problem, using ChainFire's [C.F. Lumen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.lumen) will correct it because the app uses hardware compositing, and Android doesn't notice a "layer" on top of the current screen.

Comment: Related: [Determine which app is drawing on top of other apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127769/determine-which-app-is-drawing-on-top-of-other-apps?lq=1)

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot, I think you are using screen filtering apps like Twilight, f.lux, CF.lumen or bluelight filter. Try to force stop/uninstall or disable the screen filtering apps and it will work again.

If you are not using any filtering app, try looking for your installed apps that have overlay capability, apps that can show their contents over another apps, apps with overlay permission (like- Messenger, Musixmatch, Touch Assistant apps that can float on your screen).

If you are not sure, try disable them one by one in your `Settings ⇒ Apps` and find which one is causing the problem. You can also look for "Draw over other apps" menu in your android setting where all the apps with this permission will be listed. If you couldn't locate the menu, search for overlay permission + {android version} + {device manufacturer}.

Comment: It worked. But why is this a problem?

Comment: I believe Android disabled it for the security reasons. The malicious apps might trick the user to install unwanted apps by showing something over "Install" label?

Comment: Can you tell why screen filtering app causes this issue ? Because Cancel button is working and install button alone not working ..

Comment: @logan Allowing the user to press cancel button won't hurt anyone right? Just my opnion :)

Comment: Also my copy bubble app was causing this, and it's just a tiny floating view in corner.  I had to exit this app for install button to enable.

Comment: I don't get it. I spent around 30-60min tweaking with my running apps until I was able to install my apk. Why Android doesn't show a pop up like "Are you sure you want to install example.apk to you device?", instead of disabling a button and making the user feel even irritated with something that simply doesn't work?

Comment: @TeoInke Then that battery saver+fast charging enabler+antivirus+ram cleaner+all the bloatware available in universe app will show something like 'oh your phone seems pretty slow. why not press ok button below' over your message :P

Comment: I don't understand how this is a security feature. If a malicious app can display something over install button and intercept the touch event, what would stop it from displaying something over the cancel button?

Comment: If you want to fix this without killing any apps, you can do it by going to "Settings -> Apps -> Click Settings Wheel -> Draw Over Other Apps" and disable the permission for all apps. After that you can install your 3rd party app and then restore the permission to draw over apps for any apps you like.

Comment: @user3829751 The security issue is the malicious app tricking you in to pressing install. E.g., draw something over top of the permissions display, making you think the app its installing is safe, when its not. Or draw over more of the dialog making you not realize you're installing an app at all. So when an overlay is active, the install button isn't clickable at all. OTOH, tricking you into pressing cancel is harmless. (It's a UI failure, though, that the phone doesn't explain why you can't install the app.)

Comment: @user3829751 no, pressing the cancel button does not install the app. That's the while point of the button! That's a system (privileged) dialog box, asking the user for permission to install an app. Only the user pressing install allows the app install. (Some system apps like the Play Store can install an app without the dialog, but normal apps can't)

Comment: @derobert How is tricking you into pressing cancel harmless when you could fire the same exact logic, as you would if drawing over the install button? They would both start an install process, correct?

Comment: @user3829751 no, they wouldn't. That logic is provided by the Android system, not your app. You can't change it.

Comment: @derobert So you can alter the behavior when drawing a view over the install button, but not the cancel button? That just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user3829751 no, you can't alter the behavior of either button. The install button would always install the app, the cancel button not install it. What an app can do is confuse the user (e.g., but drawing new labels on top, or a fake permission notice, fake app name, etc.)

Comment: @derobert I see, sort of like a phishing attack. Thank you for enlightening me!

Comment: FYI If you happen to be using something like 'scrcpy' you can just <TAB> over to the install button with your keyboard and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a community-curated list of some well-known/popular apps that have "Draw over other apps" permission and may cause this issue:

- Twilight
- Pixel Filter
- Facebook Messenger
- Battery Mix
- Samsung S Finder
- DU Recorder
- Lux Lite