# How do I uninstall Cool Browser?

Tags: uninstallation

There was an app called Cool Browser which always showed up as an advertisment so, I installed it because it was always showing up. I did not want to use the app, so I tried to uninstall it it but I failed (it blocked me from tapping the OK button).

How do I uninstall it?

Comment: Is this the browser you installed? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wZinZBrowser&hl=en

Comment: `it blocked me from tapping the OK button` -- What do you mean by it blocked you? Are you unable to use or see the option 'Uninstall' in Android 'Settings -> Apps' or something else not mentioned here? Besides, have you tried booting into Safe Mode and then uninstall it?

Comment: There are multiple apps listed [here](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=uninstall%20apps&c=apps&hl=en) that helps in uninstalling user installed apps. Have your tried any of them so far? What are your results?

Comment: If it's the app on geffchang's comment, then I don't have any problem uninstalling it. However, if you can't press OK, it seems it's similar to [a problem if you screen filter app](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69981/why-cant-i-press-the-install-button-when-installing-applications-from-unknown-s). However, we aren't sure because you haven't mentioned that you're using such app.

Comment: Use Link2SD or any similar app.

Comment: Is this the browser you installed? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cool.pro.coolbrowser

Answer (score 1):

I tried [Avast free antivirus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity) and this allowed me to uninstall it.