# Unable to click Next button when sideloading an APK

Tags: applications, installation

First of all my device isn't rooted. I use this device for development purpose: installing apps using ADB, starting activity, and more. What has possibly gone wrong?

When I click on Next button nothing happens. But Cancel button works fine.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

It's LG G4 International version.

Comment: As a sidenote, Lucky Patcher requires root, and some Android version require you to scroll to the end of the permission list before the Next button works.

Comment: Yaa that I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the answer. Looks like any screen color filter apps mess up this thing. Use CF.Luman to use installation feature or if you want to use the current application, disable that app for a minute to install apk to your device.

For complete info look at this thread: [Why can't I press the Install button when installing applications from unknown sources?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69981/why-cant-i-press-the-install-button-when-installing-applications-from-unknown-s)